# Как добиться эффекта движения фона при перемещении мыши?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как только заходишь на [этот сайт](http://mplsmesshall.com/) с ПК (с телефона не проверял), сразу видишь очень интересный эффект. Логотип находится на месте, не двигается, строго по центру, а вот фон движется в противоположную от движения мыши сторону. Причем там как будто бы 2 фона, один движется медленнее, другой - быстрее.

Конкретные вопросы:

1. Как добиться эффекта движения фона при движении мыши (да еще и в противоположную сторону)?
2. Как организовать движение фонов с разной скоростью, как будто один дальше, а другой - ближе.

Comment: Без плагинов и прочего, на самом деле все очень просто - слушаете движения мышки на необходимом контейнере и умножаете / отнимаете / добавляете ее позицию к элементам, которые должны "летать". Заставить лететь элемент в другую сторону настолько же просто, как добавить минус к позиции мышки. На сайте, который вы привели в пример, используется не два фона, а две группы значков, которые летают с разной скоростью - это эффективнее, чем рисовать два прозрачных больших изображения. Движения мышки на определенном элементе можно перехватить, к примеру, атрибутом onMouseMove=""

Comment: @therainycat мне кажется если человек не знает что такое паралакс эфект то без плагинов ему самому будет тяжело делать. Темболее на чистом javascript без jQuery к примеру

Comment: @Sergalas Возможно, но в вопросе об этом ничего не сказано. Я вижу в тегах javascript и html, посему пишу о javascript и html, в частности о том, как этого эффекта добились на приведенном сайте

Comment: @Sergalas не надо умничать. Прекрасно знаю, что такое параллакс (только немного в другом его проявлении), плагины не использую, пишу на чистом JS. Вопрос состоял именно в алгоритмизации процесса.

Comment: И @therainycat дал вполне себе нормальное объяснение, а именно: разъяснил, что это не изображения, а двигающиеся группы значков, и конкретно описал, где какой ивент ловить и что с ним потом делать. За что я ему и благодарен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У них на каждом из двигаюшихся элементов своя функция(что бы по разному двигалось)

Код на для одного из двигающихся элементов(прям с того сайта):

Что бы найти код воспользовася:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Функция запускается на `onMouseMove`

```
document.getElementById("move-this").addEventListener("mousemove", moveMe);
function moveMe(event) {
    // Cache mouse coordinates.
    var clientX = event.clientX;
    var clientY = event.clientY;

    // Calculate Mouse Input
    if (!this.orientationSupport && this.relativeInput) {

        // Clip mouse coordinates inside element bounds.
        if (this.clipRelativeInput) {
            clientX = Math.max(clientX, this.ex);
            clientX = Math.min(clientX, this.ex + this.ew);
            clientY = Math.max(clientY, this.ey);
            clientY = Math.min(clientY, this.ey + this.eh);
        }

        // Calculate input relative to the element.
        this.ix = (clientX - this.ex - this.ecx) / this.erx;
        this.iy = (clientY - this.ey - this.ecy) / this.ery;

    } else {

        // Calculate input relative to the window.
        this.ix = (clientX - this.wcx) / this.wrx;
        this.iy = (clientY - this.wcy) / this.wry;
    }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Это стандартный паралакс эфект вот ссылки на плагины http://helix.su/tags/parallax/ вот ещё https://habrahabr.ru/post/161941/ на самом деле их намоного больше.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.